# How can I insert a tab at an arbitrary position instead of the last?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I can add a new tab to a `TabHost` by using the `addTab()` method. But this will always add the tab as the last tab. How can I add tabs in other positions than the last in the `TabHost`? For example, how can I insert a new tab as the very first tab or into other arbitrary positions?

I don't want to use XML but everything should be done programmatically.

One solution that comes to my mind is to first remove all tabs by calling `clearAllTabs()` on the `TabHost` and then re-add all tabs in the order I want to have them. But this is of course a very hackish solution. Isn't there a nicer one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is not. If you look at the `TabHost` source code, the only way to add something to `mTabSpecs` is via the `addTab` method. Extending the class won't help either since the list is `private`.

So, as you said, using `clearAllTabs()` is the least 'hacky' way of doing it. I think the use case itself is non-trivial, so I can understand why achieving the behavior is not that straightforward. But I wouldn't call it a "very hacky" solution. There is no java reflection going on, it's simply invalidating the view container and adding a new list of views to it. It won't impact performance, nor memory, nor readability, nor it will break if the SDK updates or something like that. So I'm pretty sure it's totally fine.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get the individual tab views from the `TabHost` or do I have to manually cache them? From the doc, it looks like I can only get the current tab view by using `getCurrentTabView()`. I don't see how I can get the non-current tab views from the `TabHost` so I guess I have to manually keep track of them?

Comment: Yes. There is a method `getTabWidget` in `TabHost` which has a method `getChildTabViewAt(int index)`. This will return you a view corresponding to the given index. But make sure to check if the index is valid before using it. You can get the count tab here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget#getTabCount

Comment: Are you sure that `getChildTabViewAt()` is the right method? Doc says that it returns the tab **indicator** view whereas I'm looking for the tab **content** view. I don't see any way to get the tab content view...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Take a look at `TabHost` implementation and see how `getCurrentTabView()` is implemented. Here is what it does: `return mTabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(mCurrentTab);`. Since the `mTabWidget` can be accessed via `getTabWidget()` and the method is public, you can safely get the tab view by index from it.